# Deploy options column greyed out, and no platform choices to deploy - Visual Studio 2022, Hololens 1, Unity 2021

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm having an issue with VS where I can't select a platform to deploy to, or set any deploy options.

I'm trying to deploy a Unity (2021.1.16f) build to Hololens 1 via Visual Studio 2022.

Here are my Unity build settings:

[image: Unity build settings]

But when I open the project in VS, I can't select a deploy platform (start is the only option).

[image: Deploy options]

And, the deploy checkbox is disabled in the config manager menu.

[image: Config Manager]

I've triple checked that the project that shares a name w/ my Unity scene is set as the startup project, and that hasn't helped.

Anyone ever run into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for HoloLens 1 development, the [Unity 2019.4 LTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version#unity-20194-lts) is recommended.

> But when I open the project in VS, I can't select a deploy platform (start is the only option)

Please make sure the best matched VS version and components listed in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/install-the-tools#installation-checklist) is installed.

> Note about HoloLens (1st gen) and desktop Windows Mixed Reality
> headsets: If you are only developing applications for desktop Windows
> Mixed Reality headsets or HoloLens (1st gen), you can use **Visual**
> **Studio 2017** and use the Windows SDK installed by it.

In terms of the HoloLens 1 app deployment setting in Visual Studio, normally we will use the following ways:

1. Remote connection and deployment.

   Ensure dev PC and HoloLens device in the same local network, follow this doc to deply your app:
   [Remote connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-visual-studio?tabs=hl2#remote-connection)
2. Deploy app via USB cable. Please check out the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-visual-studio?tabs=hl#build-configuration)
3. [Deploying an app to the HoloLens (1st gen) Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-visual-studio?tabs=hl2#deploying-an-app-to-the-hololens-1st-gen-emulator)

Comment: This may seem an inane question - and "no" is answer enough - but, my situation is this:

I'm working on an application that targets the HL2, but doesn't use any of the more advanced features like hand tracking, or eye tracking - I essentially want to check if models are properly loading, and if the scale of objects looks relatively correct.

Unfortunately due to the pandemic, I have no access to the HL2, and only have an HL1.  Is there a reasonable way to test the application on the old hololens?

Comment: Fully understood! I have to say the emulator is the only way. As you are working on the hand tracking and eye tracking feature, you may need to check the [Simulation control usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-the-hololens-emulator#simulation-control-panel)